Correct way of handling metadata in pyarrow+parquet in partition + append workflow?
I have datasets, v1, v2, v3. ... coming every month in tar.gz. format. Each new version includes the previous version, thus getting bigger - but it can have some data deleted. Fortunately, each dataset has also metadata to show what is inside. I wanted to merge them into a single construct to be able to query whatever I like later (statistical analysis).
I chose pyarrow & parquet to do this (learned recently), using partitions, so the structure now is:
<dataset_root>
  _common_metadata
  _metadata
  - ver=v1
    - batch=0
        part_0.parquet
        part_1.parquet
        ...
    - batch=1
    ...
  - ver=v2
    - batch=0
      ...
    - batch=1
      ...
    ...

As the data is large (binary blobs) I process them 100k rows at a time (batches) and limit part_N.parquet files to 10k records (which are somewhere 500MB). I collect the metadata in a class attribute and write them at the end. So far so good.
When I process the second version, I get a unique index field from the existing parquet into a set, check the incoming data from tar.gz traversal against it, and only allow non-existing ones. So if I reconstruct v2, I contruct them from v1 & v2 partition. Again done...
But, at the end of the second run, the existing metadata gets over-written. As the files include binary data, I could not find a way to APPEND to the existing metadata files.
So:

How can I append to _metadata
Is there a way to visualize the whole data in _metadata file - so that perhaps I parse, append and write back?
Do I really need these metadata in this local computer work? I just like to have some statistics, I can already glob.glob into them etc.

I must be doing something wrong, all these seem odd. Any help/directions are much appreciated.
